# Spring Data Mongo Aggregation Pipeline fails

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am experimenting with the aggregation pipelines with spring integration.

I have the following data model:

```
@Document
data class Team(
    val teamName: String,
    val projects: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf(),
    var members: MutableSet<TeamMember> = mutableSetOf()
) : TenantBaseDocument() {
    @Id
    var id: String = ObjectId.get().toString()
}
```

`TenantBaseDocument` is just a tenantId

```
@Document
data class TeamMember(val userId: ObjectId, var roles: Set<TeamRole>)
```

```
@Document
data class User(
    val externalUserId: String,
    val email: String
) : TenantBaseDocument() {
    @Id
    var id: String = ObjectId.get().toString()
}
```

Now, I would like to query teams and "join" the TeamMember `userId` with the `_id` of `User`.

I tried for example this:

```
    override fun findWithMemberDetails(): List<Document> {

        val lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("user")
            .localField("members.userId")
            .foreignField("_id")
            .`as`("members.memberDetails")

        val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation)

        val results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "team", Document::class.java)
        val result =  results.mappedResults

        return listOf()
    }
```

When debugging, the `result` contains all the fields I need, however when mapping to a specific class the mapping fails.

Result class:

```
@Document
data class TeamResult(
    val teamName: String,
    val projects: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf(),
    var members: MutableSet<TeamMemberResult> = mutableSetOf()
) : TenantBaseDocument() {
    @Id
    var id: String = ObjectId.get().toString()
}
```

```
@Document
data class TeamMemberResult(var roles: MutableSet<TeamRole> = mutableSetOf(), val memberDetails: User)
```

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.instantiateClass(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:491)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:459)
```

I tried some variations with `memberDetails: List<User>` for example, but until now, nothing works unfortunately.

Log of query:

```
Executing aggregation: [{ "$lookup" : { "from" : "user", "localField" : "members.userId", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "members.memberDetails"}}] in collection team
```